# List of Used Programs

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to make a page or an entry like "List of Figures" or "List of Tables" but I would need it for "Used Programs".

I just would like to to have a list where all programs that we used are listed.

I'd be pleased if there would be a easy way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How are the 'used programs" identified to LaTeX? E.g., have you set up a `float` environment -- say, via the `\newfloat` macro of the [float](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float) package -- to display each program?

Comment: I don't need these programms directly in texmaker.
It is so that we recorded some energy waves and other stuff like that with many differnt measuring instruments and each instrument had a other software.

And also we used many other softwares to do our thesis which we need to publish in there

But these softwares or programms are not in direkt connection with TexMaker

does this help?

Comment: "Does this help?" I'm afraid not. :-( Please read the user guide of the `float` package and decide if its `\newfloat` mechanism provides a suitable vehicle for your purposes.

Comment: @Daniel: Typically a "List of ..." includes some description (perhaps a number, although not necessary) and a *page*. Do you reference these programs/software anywhere in your document so that a page number would be a relevant thing? If not, please add some more detail to your question that clearly states what you're after.

Comment: Yes we are refer to those programms in our thesis -  so we have some pagenumbers - but I do not need a number at the title.

We would also put the Link to the Download or producer side and some other stuff

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though a `description` list might meet your needs.

```
\section{Used Programs} % or \chapter
\begin{description}
\item[Proga] details
\item[Progb] details
...
\end{description}
```

Comment: This helps a lot but how do I put this in the appendix without an Number bevor?

Comment: I do not understand your vproblem